# An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I tried to open the rails console, but found the error as below:

```
rails c
Could not find nokogiri-1.6.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

then I run the `bundle install`

```
Installing nokogiri (1.6.0)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/liuxingqi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp/i686-apple-darwin11/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'install' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Activating libxml2 2.8.0 (from /Users/liuxingqi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/i686-apple-darwin11/libxml2/2.8.0)...
Extracting libxslt-1.1.26.tar.gz into tmp/i686-apple-darwin11/ports/libxslt/1.1.26... OK
Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.26 (from /Users/liuxingqi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/i686-apple-darwin11/libxslt/1.1.26)...
checking for libxml/parser.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/liuxingqi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-iconv-dir
    --without-iconv-dir
    --with-iconv-include
    --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
    --with-iconv-lib
    --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-xslt-dir
    --without-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libxslt-config
    --without-libxslt-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-libxml-2.0-config
    --without-libxml-2.0-config
    --with-libiconv-config
    --without-libiconv-config
/Users/liuxingqi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/liuxingqi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
    from /Users/liuxingqi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:970:in `block in find_header'
    from /Users/liuxingqi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/liuxingqi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/liuxingqi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/liuxingqi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/liuxingqi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/liuxingqi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /Users/liuxingqi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/liuxingqi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:969:in `find_header'
    from extconf.rb:166:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/liuxingqi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/liuxingqi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

my ruby version:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin14.0.0]
```

OS:

```
OSX Yosemite 10.10.1
```

Hope anyone can help me! Thanks.

Comment: Seams you used different nokogiri version at Gemfile.lock.

Comment: yes, I found two version: `nokogiri (~> 1.4)`, `nokogiri (1.6.0)`

Comment: Try to edit Gemfile.lock 1.4 to 1.6.0 and run bundle install again.

Comment: still same error, should I change nokogiri 1.6.0 to other version?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I delete the `Gemfile.lock`, then run `bundle install`. Everything is ok! :)

Comment: Yes. Should remove Gemfile.lock.

Comment: Removing the gemfile.lock makes you lose any reference to the installed gems, if not properly stated in the Gemfile the updated versions might break some code. Only do this when you are allowed to break code

Comment: Removing Gemfile.lock and bundle install is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: Could you share the steps to remove this Gemfile.lock ? (I have many Gemfiles..)

Comment: @A.Trejo the root directory of your project

Comment: This even worked in a Rails 7 app for me today!

Answer (score 9):

I had into this error and this is what worked for me:

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install
```

Answer (score 2):

To do  **sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev**
And Try install again

Comment: How about adding a "WHY?" we're doing this?

Comment: This is macOS not linux

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
```

Then

```
$ gem install nokogiri
```

Comment: How about adding a "WHY?" we're doing this?

Comment: This is macOS not linux

Answer (score 0):

For me, this work

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install
```